# How can I change this value from a different script? UNITY C#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Platform : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float speed = 10.0f;
    private Rigidbody2D rb;


    // Use this for initialization
    void Start()
    {
        rb = this.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
        rb.velocity = new Vector2(-speed, 0);

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        //not important
    }

    private void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D other)
    {
        //not important
    }
}
```

^^
This is my **Platform.cs**

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class PlatformSpawner : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject Platform;
    public GameObject Fireball;
    public float respawnTime = 0.1f;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start()
    {
        StartCoroutine(ObjectSpawning());
    }
    private void spawnPlatform()
    {
//not important
    }
    private void spawnFireball()
    {
//not important
    }
    IEnumerator ObjectSpawning()
    {
        while (true)
        {
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(respawnTime);
            spawnPlatform();
            spawnFireball();
            respawnTime *= 1.02f;
        }
    }
}
```

^^
This is my **PlatformSpawner.cs**

I'm new to unity and C#, how can I change the value **speed** in **Platform.cs** from **PlatformSpawner.cs** ? I looked up online but I cant seem to find an answer... So I hope you guys can help me!
I'm trying to gradually increase the speed value btw.
Thanks in advance (:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you want to change the speed for just one platform, or change for all platforms?

If you want the same speed for all platforms, you should make `speed` static.

```cs
public static float speed = 10.0f;
```

Then you can adjust the speed like this.

```cs
Platform.speed = 15.0f; //replace 15.0f with your desired speed.
```

If you want to change the speed for a specific platform, get the `Platform` component from a game object, and modify speed.

```cs
// assuming "platform" is of type gameObject
platform.GetComponent<Platform>().speed = 15.0f; // replace 15.0f with your desired speed.
```